# Non-extern function with C linkage

Tags: c++, c, linkage

Is it possible to declare a function with C linkage without it having external linkage? When trying to compile

```
extern "C" static void f() {}
```

I get

```
f.cc:1: error: invalid use of 'static' in linkage specification
```

which makes sense, in a way. In `namespace { extern "C" void f() {} }`, the `extern` specifier seems to override the anonymous namespace's restricted scope.

If this is not possible, does it matter when passing a function pointer to C?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do

```
extern "C" {
  static void f() {}
}
```

This will give the function `f`'s type C linkage which in practice means that it uses the C calling convention on your platform. The function's name will still have C++/internal linkage, because a language linkage specification only applies to function names of *external* linkage.

If you specify the `extern "C"` directly on the declaration, the Standard specifies that the `extern "C"` is taken to be also a storage class specifier, so if you would add `static`, then you would get a conflict.

> Does it matter when passing a function pointer to C

It can theoretically matter - an implementation is allowed to differ in behavior from calling a function whose type has C++ linkage to calling a function whose type has C linkage. I don't know of implementation details though, just what the spec says about it. Best to follow the spec and you are safe.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted: `undefined reference to 'f'` ;) Why didn't I think of this. Thanks!

Comment: "an implementation is allowed to differ in behavior" -- I was specifically thinking of functions that take `char` arguments and the C rule that such arguments are promoted to type `int`.

Comment: @larsmans oh such things are done as specified by c++ laws. that is, if you say `extern "C" void f() { }` then calling `f('a')` is not allowed in C++. So the issue dos not arise. And if you say `extern "C" void f(char x) { }`, then calling `f('a')`, it behaves just as in C. In C, a function `void f(char x) { }` called by `char y = 'a'; f(a)` also passes `y` as a char, no promotion happens. But the actual argument passing (i.e order of parameter allocation on stack, register use, etc) may be different.

Comment: of course if you have a C function `void f(char x) { }` and declare that function as `extern "C" void f(int x);` in C++, you do it wrong - both need to use `f(char x)` or both `f(int x)`. Or you need to define your C function as `void f(x) char x; { }` (which will be compatible with the C++ version taking `int`).

Comment: I've put in an `extern "C"` block to be on the safe side.

Comment: Re function pointers: IIRC there has only been one real-world system with different ABIs for C and C++ - perhaps Solaris?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the function pointer to a C++ non-member or static member function into a C function and should just work unless you specified a different calling convention for that C++ function. Regular C++ function should use the C calling convention so you're good on that front.

The main reason passing a pointer to a non-static member function doesn't work that easily is because you'll somehow need to pass the information about the object's `this` pointer as well, which normally happens as an implicit, non-visible parameter for any member function.

Answer (score 0):

I just successfully used Johannes answer. Thanks dude!

Since I cannot (yet) comment, but *can* answer, let me just add this data point.

I typed, in `<the-file>.cpp` (details mercifully omitted :-) :

```
extern "C" {
    extern int myfunction(<the-args>);
}

extern int myfunction(<the-args>) {
    <the-code>
}
```

and also:

```
extern "C" {
    static int myfunction(<the-args>);
}

static int my function(<the-args>) {
    <the-code>
}
```

I compiled both ways, and did a:

```
nm -g <the-file>.o | grep myfuncion
```

on the two object files in turn.

I observed that for extern, the was an entry, but for the static case, there was none.

So I am happy enough for now that the outer "extern" just sets up the linkage, and the addressing mode is static for the static case.